# How to insert the symbol 'Infinite' in Excel programmatically?

Tags: java, excel

How can I create the "Infinite" symbol in an excel sheet programmatically?

Preferably from Java...but other tips are also welcome.

Thx.

Comment: You might want to elaborate what method you use to access Excel from Java.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "Infinity Symbol" character is in codepoint 0x221E in unicode. The VBA code to do it would be this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = ChrW(&h221E)
```

Hope this helps.